# Date and Time with MongoDB and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, timezone

I am using MongoDB with rails3, i need to store all the date formats in EST, i am using timestamps. even i configured app.rb with 
    config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
But it seems doing nothing.
can some one guide me, so that i need to store in EST and even while displaying, it should display in EST format only.

Comment: Looks like they're always UTC (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date) inside MongoDB. Why don't you deal with the time zones and formatting issues outside your database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following lines in my mongoid.yml in defaults

```
    use_activesupport_time_zone: true
    use_utc: false
```

after adding this line with  config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' in application.rb, everything is storing in EST format. It is because we don't have active record for mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't handle timezone informations. You need to save this information in another field of your collection and handle it by yourself.